# How to keep Div rotated with css after flip?

Tags: html, css, webkit-transform

I found [this](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) tutorial on how to CSS flip a div. You can find the result [here](http://kevintimmer.nl/sbk/index.php). now the thing is, i want to keep the puzzle piece flipped to the back after the hover so the information on the back remains visible. Now i'm not very strong in working with css3. So any help on realizing the desired would be very appreciated!

Here is the code i'm using:

html:

```
 <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
       <div class="puzzel-stuk">
           <div class="front" style="background:url('img/puzzel-links-boven-gesloten.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 323px; height: 429px;"></div>
           <div class="back" style="background:url('img/puzzel-links-boven-open.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 323px; height: 429px; text-align:left;">  
           <div class="stap-title">
              <h1>Stap 1</h1>
           </div>
           <div class="stap-tekst" style="margin-left:10px;">
              Kies een geschikte achtergrond,<br/>
              zodat uw brief meer opvalt<br/>
              bij uw potentiële werkgever.
           </div>                         
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
 /* simple */
 .flip-container {
      -webkit-perspective: 1000;
      -moz-perspective: 1000;
      -ms-perspective: 1000;
      perspective: 1000;
      -ms-transform: perspective(1000px);
      -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
      -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
      -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }

   /*
   .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper, #flip-toggle.flip .flipper {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
   filter: FlipH;
   -ms-filter: "FlipH";
   }
   */

   /* START: Accommodating for IE */
   .flip-container:hover .back, .flip-container.hover .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
   }

  .flip-container:hover .front, .flip-container.hover .front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

        /* END: Accommodating for IE */

        .flip-container, .front, .back {
            width: 320px;
            height: 427px;          
            font-size:18px;
            display:inline-block;
            float:left;
        }

        .flipper {
            -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -ms-transition: 0.6s;

            -moz-transition: 0.6s;
            -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
            -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

            transition: 0.6s;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

            position: relative;
        }

        .front, .back {
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;

            -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

            -moz-transition: 0.6s;
            -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

            -o-transition: 0.6s;
            -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

            -ms-transition: 0.6s;
            -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

            transition: 0.6s;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .front {
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            background: lightgreen;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .back {
            background: lightblue;
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
            -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
            -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
            transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        }

        .front .name {
            font-size: 2em;
            display: inline-block;
            background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
            color: #f8f8f8;
            font-family: Courier;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            bottom: 60px;
            left: 25%;
            position: absolute;
            text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;
            display: none;

            -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
            transform: rotate(-20deg);
        }

        .back-logo {
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px;
            left: 90px;
            width: 160px;
            height: 117px;
            background: url(logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
        }

        .back-title {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #00304a;
            position: absolute;
            top: 180px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #acd7e5;
            font-family: Courier;
            font-size: 2em;
        }

        .back p {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 40px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }

        /* vertical */
        .vertical.flip-container {
            position: relative;
        }

            .vertical .back {
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                transform: rotateX(180deg);
            }

            .vertical.flip-container .flipper {
                -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
                -moz-transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
                -ms-transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
                transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
            }

            /*
            .vertical.flip-container:hover .flipper {
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
                -ms-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
                transform: rotateX(-180deg);
            }
            */

            /* START: Accommodating for IE */
            .vertical.flip-container:hover .back, .vertical.flip-container.hover .back {
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
                -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
                -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
                transform: rotateX(0deg);
            }

            .vertical.flip-container:hover .front, .vertical.flip-container.hover .front {
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                transform: rotateX(180deg);
            }
        /* END: Accommodating for IE */

        .stap-title {
            width:40%;
            margin:0 auto;
            margin-top:10px;
            display:block;
            position:relative;
        }

        .stap-tekst {
            margin-left:10px;
            margin-right:10px;
            margin-top:20px;
            display:block;
            width:auto;         
            position:relative;  
        }
```

Comment: I have checked your site. Looks like flip is working on hover. what is the actual problem?

Comment: I'd like it to stay flipped so the information on the back of the puzzle stays visible.

Comment: so once hover happened it will stay in flip mode until you need to refresh the page again. is it something like that?

Comment: Yes correct, once flipped a puzzle piece it needs to stay flipped until the page is refreshed.

Comment: r u ok with jquery solutions?

Comment: sure, as long as it works and i can fix it :)

Comment: i have given answer. check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following jquery code in your file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.flip-container').hover(function(){
      $(this).addClass('hoverfixed');
   });
});
```

Add the following two Classes in your CSS.

```
.hoverfixed .back{
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) !important;
-moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) !important;
-o-transform: rotateY(0deg) !important;
-ms-transform: rotateY(0deg) !important;
transform: rotateY(0deg) !important;
}

.hoverfixed  .front{
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) !important;
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) !important;
-o-transform: rotateY(180deg) !important;
transform: rotateY(180deg) !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've integrated the above code and it works like a charm! :)

Comment: :) i just asked you select it my answer using the tick mark.